# Shortest Common String Problem is NP

Tags: np-complete

Does anyone know how to prove that Shortest Common String Problem is NP?
I can provide a proof that it is NP-hard but I don't know how to prove SCSS in NP.

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest common (sub)string typically be of length **one**?

Answer (score 0):

Problems in NP are decision problems, not optimization problems. I would suggest formulating the Common Substring Problem as follows:

**Instance:** Let $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2} \in \Sigma^{*}$, and let $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

**Decision:** Does there exist a string $\gamma$ of length at most $k$ s.t. $\gamma$ is a substring of both $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}$?

Now such a string $\gamma$ is your certificate. Can you verify in polynomial time that $\gamma$ is a substring of both $\omega_{1}, \omega_{2}$ and $|\gamma| \leq k$?